# Inserting unique value into database PGSQL/MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, insert-into, not-exists

I'm trying to insert unique records in a MSSQL and Postgresql DB using insert into where not exists. But I am getting a incorrect syntax error as seen below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO settings (id, title, description)
VALUES  (1, 'imageHeight', 'Image Height')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * from settings where id = 1);
```

Error:
**[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.**

Comment: I can't speak for MSSQL but on Postgres there's no `WHERE` clause for `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO settings (id, title, description)
    SELECT 1, 'imageHeight', 'Image Height'
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM settings WHERE id = 1);
```

[sql server sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd901/2)

[postgresql sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ef87b/1)

`WHERE` is a filter for results which are not typically pertinent to `INSERT` operations.